# request.contentLength returns -1

Tags: c#-4.0

In my c# application(.net 4) I want to calculate the total upload and download data size in KB, following is the code, and the problem is 'request.contentLength' always  return -1.Is 'request.contentLength'(for upload data calculation)  and 'response.contentLength'(for download data calculation) are the correct statement for calculating this data?

```
private string pageFetch(string url,int requestTimeOut)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = requestTimeOut;
        if (!Program.proxyType.Equals("None"))
        {
            int iPortNo = 0;
            try
            {
                iPortNo = Int32.Parse(Program.proxyPort);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                iPortNo = 0;
            }
            WebProxy objProxy = new WebProxy(Program.proxyAddress, iPortNo);
            if (!Program.proxyUsername.Equals(""))
            {
                objProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Program.proxyUsername, Program.proxyPassword);
            }
            request.Proxy = objProxy;
        }
        HttpWebResponse response=null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }


        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (response.ContentLength>0)
            totalDownload += (response.ContentLength / 1024);
            if(request.ContentLength>0)
            totalUpload += (request.ContentLength/1024);
            Console.WriteLine("Request length**********" + request.ContentLength);
            Console.WriteLine("Up=======" + totalUpload + "Down======" + totalDownload);
        }

        Program.comment("Response Status=" + response.StatusCode);
        string output = "";
        if (response != null)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

             // output processing

            }
            else
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Output=" + output);
        return output;
    }
```

The pageFetch(string url,int requestTimeOut) method runs inside a  TPL.

Answer (score 1):

The ContentLength property contains the value of the Content-Length header returned with the response. If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1.

Refer **[HttpWebResponse.ContentLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength.aspx)**